# Web API large File Post OutOfMemoryException error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, out-of-memory

I am trying to upload a large file (500MB) with Web API post call, but I m getting error,

`Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.`

I am getting exception at below line of code,

```
var X=  HttpClient.PostAsync(http://localhost/API/Post, Content = {byte[524288000]})
```

The API `POST` method also not called and before that I am getting the exception. What need to be done to work it.

My http request size is also bigger one,
`<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="716800" />`

API Code,

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                await fs.WriteAsync(Content , 0, Content .Length);
            }
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code? What is the Content object? StreamContent? ByteArrayContent?

Comment: @John, API code I updated, I m just sending bytes to my API method and writing with file stream

Comment: So you're using `ByteArrayContent`?

Comment: Yes, correct John

Comment: I'm still confused about your question. `PostAsync` represents the client and the other code is where you're posting _to_, right? But you're getting the error in the _client_, right?

Comment: Use `StreamContent` and not `ByteArrayContent` on client (I assume exception happens on client and not on server).

Comment: Yes, error happens at client only `PostAsync`

Comment: @John & @Evk, If I need to send `StreamContent` instead of `ByteArrayContent`, then I need to change the API code as above?

Comment: `StreamContent` and `ByteArrayContent` both send the raw data.

Comment: @john, mean will also get `OutOfMemoryException` error with `StreamContent` as well?

Comment: StreamContent, as implied by "Stream", doesn't load all of the data into memory at once but instead streams it.

Answer (score 0):

Use StreamWriter instead to directly insert the content into your file:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath)) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<=Content.Length;i++)
        {
            sw.WriteAsync("this is an example");
        }
    }
```

This is just a snippet but if your file doesn't exist, `StreamWriter`  will create it for you.

Comment: Is for loop required. I used `sw.WriteAsync(Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(Content), 0, fContent.Length);`

Comment: Not it is not, I used it just for the snippet.